# Is it possible to generate a sitemap.xml for each variation in a site collection?

Tags: 2013, web, variations, seo

We made a website with SharePoint as our cms. Is it possible to generate a `sitemap.xml` for each site collection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it on every site collection, there is site collection feature called **Search Engine Sitemap**

> This feature improves the search engine optimization of a website by
>   automatically generating a search engine sitemap on a recurring basis
>   that contains all valid URLs in a SharePoint website. Anonymous access
>   must be enabled in order to use this feature.

Also have a look https://blog.mastykarz.nl/search-engine-optimization-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: i know that there ist the Feature for the Site Collection and we use it currently. But we want each **Variation** (which is a site per definition) to have it's own `sitemap.xml` as it is recommended by the Google Search Console.